# Why nslookup result always comes from server 127.0.0.1

Tags: 12.04

I find quite confused that **nslookup** always get result from **Server 127.0.0.1**

Does it because Ubuntu uses a local DNS cache by **dnsmasq**? But I have closed it and flushed my dns cache, then nslookup a host that I have never visited, then the output is still 127.0.0.1.

That makes me quite confused. Can anyone explain this for me?
By the way, my DNS server is set to 8.8.8.8.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default Ubuntu does indeed cache DNS entries with Dnsmasq. Dnsmasq does a lookup when a DNS entry is not in its cache, which is why you'll always see the `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`) IP address  when doing a DNS lookup without specifying the nameserver.

In the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/dnsmasq.8.html) it's explained as follows:

> Dnsmasq accepts DNS queries and  either  answers  them  from  a  small,
>   local,  cache  or  forwards  them  to a real, recursive, DNS server. It
>   loads the contents of /etc/hosts so that local hostnames which  do  not
>   appear  in  the global DNS can be resolved and also answers DNS queries
>   for DHCP configured hosts.

This behaviour can be overridden by editing `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and changing `dns=dnsmasq` to `#dns=dnsmasq`, after which you'll need to restart the network-manager service (`sudo service network-manager restart`).

More information can be found in the [community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq) and in the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/dnsmasq.8.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I haven't realized that it it Dnsmasq does a lookup when a DNS entry is not in cache. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what to do if there is already no `dns=dnsmasq` line?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell: this answer is outdated: I believe Ubuntu switched to `systemd-resolved` in version 17.04. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/907246/how-to-disable-systemd-resolved-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

check if

cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

[main]

plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]

managed=false

hash(#) out dns=dnsmasq

save the file and restart networking.

> > > #### If you don’t want a local resolver you can turn it off DNSMASQ using the following procedure

You need to edit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file

```
gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

and comment out the following line from

```
dns=dnsmasq
```

to

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```

Save and exit the file

Now you need to network-manager using the following command

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

Ref: http://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/