# Wifi not working in Ubuntu 17.10 version on Lenovo ThinkPad E450

Tags: wireless, 17.10

I upgraded my Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10. After the upgrade Wifi stopped working. I am using Lenovo ThinkPad E450 laptop. Sharing network information https://cloud.acrobat.com/file/274e230c-0e29-4f22-9c68-0eb76e089717

Comment: please put your information somewhere open, preferably in the question, but if you must, at http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I just faced this problem yesterday after upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10 as well. My laptop is a Thinkpad X230. I use the solution from Bastian Voigt in this post and my internet connection was resolved.
https://askubuntu.com/a/907249/809437

Answer (score 10):

Issue resolved after doing following steps

1. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`
2. Say yes to `prepare /etc/resolve.conf for dynamic updates?`
3. Reboot

Comment: sudo service network-manager restart

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to 17.10 yesterday, and had similar problem. It was a kernel issue related to wireless drivers and supplicant. I switched to an earlier stable version of kernel which I used in 17.04. Now everything works fine. Hope they fix it in next update.

Comment: Kindly share the kernel switching steps

Comment: Do you get a grub prompt to select the OS when you start the laptop/PC? If not, add /update as below in ` /etc/default/grub` and then run `sudo update-grub`. Now you should get a grub screen at startup where you can go in "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and choose the kernel version u want to boot.
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Comment: I tried with older kernel 4.10,but its not working for me.Do I need to change anything in /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf ? current value is "options iwlwifi nohwcrypt=1"

Answer (score 0):

I have to use kernel no higher than 4.12.* from the mainline kernel ppa.
Everything lower worked fine up until 4.13. And I've been able to keep updating to to newer versions of 4.12.x even after 4.13 and 4.14 came out, as it went from 4.12.1 up to currently 4.12.14, but no 4.13 or 4.14.

I have Intel 4965 wifi card.

I type "ubuntu mainline" into google, and take the top link.
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/
Scroll down to 4.12, then to the highest number of 4.12
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.12.14/

Then in there I download 3 things under the amd64 section OR under the i386 section, depending on which laptop I'm on:

```
linux-headers...all.deb
linux-headers...generic...amd64.deb
linux-image...generic...amd64.deb
```

Then open a terminal window

```
cd Downloads
ls *.deb  #(just to verify there's no other *.debs in there)
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
rm *.deb
```

Then reboot

Then I use synaptic to search for 4.14, 4.13, 4.12 etc and remove any versions I don't want, and just keep the one current version, and usually one older version. By removing the unwanted versions, I don't have to manually select the working one at boot.

I have to do this on at least 4 different laptops. 3 of them have 32bit CPUs, so for those I use the ...i386.deb instead of ...amd64.deb . Other than that, all the same steps, and the same problem and same fix. They all have to stay at 4.12.*

In my case the actual symptoms are that a kernel module IS getting loaded under the newer 4.13/4.14 kernels, and it even partially works, because it can show me the list of access points in range. But I can't actually connect to ANY access point, not even public ones with no encryption or WEP or WPA or anything.

I've had the problem for many months, ever since the first 4.13 came out.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded Lenovo G710 (Broadcom 43142) from  KUbuntu 14.04 to 17.10, but Wifi did not work. Driver *bcmwl-kernel-source* was installed, but

> sudo modprobe wl

returned error "Required key not available". It turned out, that installer did not turn off Secure boot. It should actually remain off from previous installation. After turning it off manually in UEFI(BIOS), Wifi works.

Answer (score 0):

I also suffered the same problem when i reinstalled 17.10 based kubuntu because the first installation crashed somehow. I searched for the solution on many forums but never successful. But the real solution was so simple and was looking me in the face all the times. All i did was to use MACCHANGER to change the make with -r only once and everything was back to normal again. Try it yourself. 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue few days ago. I am using Ubuntu 17.10 in my Lenovo G5080. It got fixed when I installed the driver

> Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n

Steps:

> Go to software & updates
>
> click on Additional drivers
>
> It will show Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n
>
> Select it and click on Apply changes

I would also recommend to update and upgrade via terminal using

> $ sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade

You are done. Hope that helps.