# How do I disable systemd-resolved and replace with something sane on Ubuntu 18?

Tags: dns

I've decided systemd-resolved is irretrievably broken garbage and I'd like to replace.  I've got my own local DNS server at 192.168.1.2 I'd like.  I'd *also* like to connect to a VPN with NetExtender that gives me a DNS server for a .local domain.  I would like these two things to work together, what can I do?

Comment: The best answer to this for Ubuntu 18 was given here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1195074/376218

Comment: true true:systemd-resolved is irretrievably broken garbage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable systemd-resolved in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907246/how-to-disable-systemd-resolved-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 6):

The answer by Gannet is incorrect. If you want to use plain ifupdown like in earlier releases, without netplan or NetworkManager (e.g. on a server), with dhcp, you need to do this:

```
systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
systemctl stop systemd-resolved.service

# check if resolv.conf is pointing to resolvconf
ls -la /etc/resolv.conf
# lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 May  7 16:15 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
# if not, delete /etc/resolv.conf and symlink it like this: 
rm /etc/resolv.conf
ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

# this will remove the resolved stub resolver entry from resolv.conf
resolvconf -d systemd-resolved

# fix dhclient scripts
chmod -x /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/resolved
chmod +x /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/resolvconf

# on my machine just chmod -x wasn't enough, I had to move the resolved script somewhere else
mv /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/resolved ~

# ifdown/ifup your interface to regenerate resolv.conf (or systemctl restart ifup@eth0)
ifdown eth0; ifup eth0

# check /etc/resolv.conf has the right settings
```

Comment: You, sir, are one of those unknown heroes that save the day.

Answer (score 3):

You can always disable your systemd-resolved by
`systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service`
command. And run:
`sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf && sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`
to use `/etc/resolv.conf` config as it was earlier in previous ubuntu versions.

Comment: can it be removed via apt ?

Answer (score -1):

Both answers can lead to issues with VPN. Also, if it's desired to keep NetworkManager, the following can be done:

Unlink resolvconf if this is linked to resolvectl:

```
ls -lah $(which resolvconf)
```

If resolveconf is linked to resolvectl, like the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/resolvconf -> /usr/bin/resolvectl
```

We need to unlink it:

```
sudo unlink /usr/local/bin/resolvconf
```

Now, install resolvconf because most VPN uses it:

```
sudo apt-get install resolvconf
```

set `dns=none` to `[main]` section in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[main]
...
dns=none
```

Now, we have two options here:

- Manually set DNSes system-wide
- Use resolvconf to set DNS:

### Manually set DNSes system-wide

Place desired DNS servers as nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

### Use resolvconf to set DNS

This is preferred way if you're using a VPN with specific DNS servers configured through it

```
sudo ln -sfn /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: I followed your guide and now I have no internet. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I made a new post about this. Feel free to comment there. Thanks https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438645/modified-dns-settings-to-fix-wireguard-but-disabled-internet

Comment: @Alex could you please post modified files content?
- ls -lah $(which resolvconf)
- /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
- /etc/resolv.conf