# Modified DNS Settings to Fix Wireguard but Disabled Internet

Tags: dns

I followed meetnicks post here [How do I disable systemd-resolved and replace with something sane on Ubuntu 18?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081832/how-do-i-disable-systemd-resolved-and-replace-with-something-sane-on-ubuntu-18/1427807#1427807)

to fix my wireguard connection and now I cannot connect to the web at all. I'm running 22.10 and would like to reset the DNS settings so I could get back on the web. Thanks!