# Using dnsmasq broke dig and more

Tags: networking, dns, dnsmasq, 18.10

I am trying to set up `dnsmasq` as an address resolver on an Ubuntu 18.10.

So far I disabled `systemd-resolved` as the default resolver and brought `dnsmasq` in. Running `netstat -tulpn` shows the following:

```
> sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31609/dnsmasq       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      561/sshd            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4614/openvpn        
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      31609/dnsmasq       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      561/sshd            
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           31609/dnsmasq       
udp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XX.XX:YY        0.0.0.0:*                           440/systemd-network 
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                31609/dnsmasq
```

I think this is fine so far, as now `dnsmasq` is listening on port 53.

My `/etc/resolv.conf` looks like this:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 127.0.1.1
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

I am not sure about the second line, but I think this should be fine so far, too.

Nevertheless, when I try to run `dig`, `ping` or whatever, the connection always times out:

```
> dig askubuntu.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-3ubuntu5-Ubuntu <<>> askubuntu.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Where did I do something wrong, so I broke those functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`systemd-resolved` is still running, as I see 127.0.0.53 in your `/etc/resolv.conf`.

If `dnsmasq` was running, it would show 127.0.0.1.

When you run both together, they tend to step on each others toes.

To run `dnsmsaq`, and to disable the DNS functionality of `systemd-resolved`, you need to edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and...

change:

```
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

to:

```
DNSStubListener=no
```

then reboot, recheck `/etc/resolv.conf` and you should see 127.0.0.1.

postnote: do **NOT** manually edit `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that seemed to work. Although I had to delete the symlink like written [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907246/how-to-disable-systemd-resolved-in-ubuntu) and create a blank `resolv.conf` afterwards. Now `dig` and alike work again. Why shouldn't you touch the `resolv.conf` by hand (normally)?

Comment: @flomei first reason... it says right in the file not to manually edit it. second reason... if you do edit the file, then reboot, you'll lose all of your edits anyway.

Comment: resolv.conf gets rewritten live, so it's not just at reboot - it might be if your wifi goes down and comes up again, or so.

Comment: @flomei don't just create a blank /etc/resolv.conf. Recreate the proper symlink that points to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`.