# Samba Internal DNS - Systemd resolve safe to disable?

Tags: 16.04, networking, 18.04, samba, dns

So I had a Ubuntu 16.04 instance running a samba ad dc, I upgraded to 18.04 and when starting samba I was getting the error;

> [2018/12/27 11:09:56.483755,  0]
>   ../source4/dsdb/dns/dns_update.c:290(dnsupdate_nameupdate_done)
>   ../source4/dsdb/dns/dns_update.c:290: Failed DNS update - with error
>   code 110

After some digging and running `sudo lsof -i :53` I could see

```
systemd-r  767 systemd-resolve   12u  IPv4  18656      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.53:domain 
systemd-r  767 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  18657      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:domain (LISTEN)
samba     1594            root   36u  IPv6  23058      0t0  TCP *:domain (LISTEN)
samba     1594            root   38u  IPv6  23059      0t0  UDP *:domain
```

Which lead me to disable `systemd-resolve` using the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907246/how-to-disable-systemd-resolved-in-ubuntu), this has fixed all my problems within the network (other domain machines not being able to `apt-get update` etc) but im worndering is disabling `systemd-resolve` safe ?

### Edit

This is a VM running on vsphere 6.0 its a bridged networked. Netplan folder is empty after the upgrade (which Ive just remembered should have to be set) the old network details `/etc/network/interfaces` is set to;

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens160
iface ens160 inet static
address 192.168.2.23
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.254

dns-nameservers 192.168.2.23
dns-search MYDOMAINNAME.co.uk
```

**I can manually set the `resolv.conf` (after removing the sym link) to the following and it works**

```
nameserver 192.168.2.23
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search MYDOMAIN.co.uk
DNSStubListener=no
```

Answer (score 5):

Re-enable systemd-resolve.

Two possibilities...

1. **Regarding `dnsmasq` and `systemd-resolved`...**

Do a `ps auxc | grep -i dns` and `ps auxc | grep -i resolv` and look for `dnsmasq` and `systemd-resolved`, and if both are running, you need to disable the DNS part of `systemd-resolved` by editing `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and...

change:

```
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

to:

```
DNSStubListener=no
```

then restart systemd-resolve and dnsmasq, or reboot.

2. **you MAY need to reset the symlink that is /etc/resolv.conf** (*if dnsmasq is not running*)...

`sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.OLD` # save the old symlink

`sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` # create new symlink

**Update #1:**

Many details of this installation came forward in the comments, and we still don't have a final working solution. Here are some points to recognize...

---

`DNSStubListener=no` does not belong in `/etc/resolv.conf`. (*`/etc/resolv.conf` should not (normally) be edited directly*). It's an edit to `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`. `DNS=` can also be edited there to add DNS server addresses.

---

`/etc/resolv.conf` should be a symlink, linked to one of two possible locations in /run.

```
NEW -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
OLD -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

and should contain either 127.0.0.53 (*or 127.0.0.1 if dnsmasq was running*), or DNS nameserver addresses, or your router's address (*ex: 192.168.1.1*)

---

If you're going to use NetworkManager instead of netplan, then `/etc/netplan` should contain at least one .yaml file containing...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

followed by...

`sudo netplan generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply configuration

---

If you're using NetworkManager, then `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` should exist... and should look something like...

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

---

If `dnsmasq` AND `systemd-resolve` are running, then you should do #1 in my answer.

If `dnsmasq` is not running, and `systemd-resolve` is running, then you should do #2 in my answer.

---

Comment: When i run `ps auxc | grep -i dns` there is no output (pressumeably because I have disabled `systemd-resolve`, I will try this a minute when a machine has finished its upgrade

Comment: That command is looking for dnsmasq. You must not be running it. Re-enable systemd-resolve, and then `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and you'll probably see 127.0.0.53 indicating that systemd-resolve is managing `/etc/resolv.conf`. Try item #2 in my answer then.

Comment: `/run/systemd/resolve/` doesn't exist but i restored the original resolv.conf adding the line `DNSStubListener=no` and this appears to have fixed the issue

Comment: @Dan That should be `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`, It will only be there if systemd-resolve is running. Great news! Please remember to accept my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Just rebooted and tried again, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Dan  Just curious... what does `cat /etc/resolv.conf` show?

Comment: it shows the usual spiel and then `## No DNS servers known.` but samba_dnsupdate works along with the rest of the samba and the network using the server for dns ?

Comment: @Dan  That's why I asked about `/etc/resolv.conf`. Show me the `cat` as it is now. Then remove the `DNSStubListener=no`, restart systemd-resolve, and show me the `cat `again. I want to see `/etc/resolv.conf` before AND after systemd-resolve is restarted. Also see if `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` exists.

Comment: `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` now exists, this has broken the setup both  before and after `DNSStubListener=no` it shows `# No DNS servers known.` it has broken it because re-allowing `DNSStubListener` has blocked the port for samba

Comment: @Dan  You're not following my instructions exactly. I wanted you to remove `DNSStubListener=no`, restart systemd-resolve, and I asked for TWO `cat /etc/resolv.conf` from before and after systemd-resolve has been restarted. Now I also need `cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`. Exactly when do you see the "no DNS servers known" error message?

Comment: I followed your instructions and im saying regardless of whether the `DNSStubListener` is enabled / disabled it shows `#No DNS servers known.` When I cat the file `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` it says `#No DNS servers known.`

Comment: @Dan ah, I get it. Are you using wired or wireless connection? Is your computer connected to a hub/switch/router/modem? Is your connection profile set to DHCP?

Comment: @Dan I just looked back to your question, and when you did the instructions at the link you gave, did you do "Then put the following line in the [main] section of your /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf: dns=default". If so, that's probably one reason why it's broken. Unfortunately DNS is really broken in 18.xx, and sometimes it takes some playing around like we're doing to get it working mostly.

Comment: This is a vm using 18.04.1 there is no NetworkManager folder, this was solved simply by setting `DNSStubListener=no` as its spawning a process thats blocking port 53

Comment: @Dan Ah again. More good details to know. Does DNS work on your host machine? What OS is your host... Windows or Ubuntu or something else? Is this Virtualbox, and if so, is your network setting set to NAT or something else?

Comment: @Dan edit your question to include `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Thanks.

Comment: please see the edit question this is a production server so I may have to manually make the `resolv.conf` with `DNSStubListener=no`

Comment: @Dan I've added a semi-detailed Update #1 to my answer. Please review it and make sure that it matches your current/final configuration. Ask questions if you like.