# Ubuntu Server Name Resolution fails after upgrading to 20.04 from 18.04

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, dns, resolv.conf

Immediately after upgrading Ubuntu Server from 18.04 to 20.04 name resolution stopped working. If I edit /etc/resolv.conf and replace `nameserver 127.0.0.1` with `nameserver 8.8.8.8` then everything works until reboot when /etc/resolv.conf is overwritten again. I have read that it should be 127.0.0.53 in resolv.conf but mine is 127.0.0.1 and even setting it to 127.0.0.53 doesn't work.

I have read many similar problems but none have actual solutions just work arounds that don't address the problem. Any help finding the answer would be appriciated.

Comment: Here's how to disable resolved. [How to disable systemd-resolved in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907246/how-to-disable-systemd-resolved-in-ubuntu) Afterwards, you can delete the /etc/resolv.conf symlink and make your own /etc/resolv.conf file.

Comment: Why would I want to disable the intended resolver though? This is not fixing the problem it is just a workaround.

Comment: The [documentation for resolved](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.html#) explains the DNS settings and which configuration files to edit.

Comment: I have restored from backup to 18.04

Comment: Having the same problem. Been running Ubuntu 20.04 for about a year and it started happening suddenly.